# No module named 'sklearn' after installing sklearn

Tags: python, macos, scikit-learn, pip

some package that I install in my machine (mac os) doesn't install properly

for example, I tried to install [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) by writing:

```
sudo pip3 install -U scikit-learn
```

but when I use it in my code it doesn't run and throw this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

and the interesting part is it works on IPython shell and doesn't throw the error

what is the problem? how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when something like this happens the problem is that your `pip3` installs the package in a place that your `python` cant access. If you look in the installation logs it will actually say where it installed the package. Then you just have to check that that path is in your `sys.path` list (do `import sys` first). Most likely it is not, so you can directly append the path (ending in "site-packages") to `sys.path`, or make sure you use the version of pip that actually installs packages in the right place. I recommend the latter.

If you are using Anaconda, then you just need to make sure that executing `which pip3` in the terminal shows you the path to a pip installation that is in your Anaconda folder. If that is not the case, the problem is probably that your PATH variable should have the path to your `anaconda3/bin` folder inside it.

If you are not using Anaconda, then make sure that `which python` and `which pip3` gives you matching paths. Again, this is probably not the case, and you should fix that by exporting the appropriate `bin` path to your PATH variable.

Answer (score 4):

The [import](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#machine-learning-the-problem-setting) is not the same as the [install](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html).

#### Install

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

#### Import

```
>>> from sklearn import datasets
```

Comment: I know that. the error is because I try to import it but python says it's not installed which is installed

Comment: @MohammadReza: Your install command is not correct: `sudo pip3 install -U sklearn`

Comment: you're right my bad, I also used pip install -U scikit-learn but it didn't work

Comment: OK. Can you separate the issue for import from install and post both errors please? It seems like it might be a Python versioning issue where your IPython shell sees sklearn installed and your code does not. Please elaborate on where your code is running and post the error msg

Comment: @Mohammad Reza Did you run pip install inside the environment where Python is installed ?